# When will the API V3.0 be updated for 2016 Rates

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

According to the API overview:

"Beginning October 23, 2015: The Finder Plan Benefits and Coverage API will be updated to include 2016 plan year data."

I could very well be entering the wrong effective date:

<p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>2016-01-01</p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>

I get no results.  Am I going about this wrong or is the data not available yet?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a well-formatted request that returns a response for 2016-01-01 as the effective date (except for the [...] in plan IDs). The data are available, so if your request is noticeably different from this it should be an issue with your request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:PlanBenefitRequest xmlns:p="http://hios.cms.org/api" xmlns:p1="http://hios.cms.org/api-types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://hios.cms.org/api hios-api-11.0.xsd ">

<p:Enrollees>
    <p1:DateOfBirth>1982-03-03</p1:DateOfBirth>
    <p1:Gender>Male</p1:Gender>

    <p1:Relation>SELF</p1:Relation>
    <p1:InHouseholdIndicator>true</p1:InHouseholdIndicator>
  </p:Enrollees>

    <p:Location>
    <p1:ZipCode>06001</p1:ZipCode>
     <p1:County>
         <p1:FipsCode>09003</p1:FipsCode>
         <p1:CountyName>HARTFORD</p1:CountyName>
         <p1:StateCode>CT</p1:StateCode>
    </p1:County>
  </p:Location>

  <p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>2015-01-01</p:InsuranceEffectiveDate>
  <p:Market>Individual</p:Market>
  <p:PlanIds><p:PlanId>86545CT1230005</p:PlanId>
<p:PlanId>76962CT0010002</p:PlanId>
[...]
<p:PlanId>86542CT0150045</p:PlanId>
</p:PlanIds>
   </p:PlanBenefitRequest>
```

Answer (score 1):

10/23/2015: As of today, this message is on the [Finder API Overview page](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services)

[image: Screen grab of notification of availability of 2016 data]